# Error installing oracle 19c database pre-install on oracle linux server 7.6

Tags: linux, yum, oracle-linux, oracle-database, oracle

I'm tryin to install oracle 19c on oracle linux 7.6, I'm required to install oracle 19c preinstall , knowing that this is a fresh install I don't understand why i'm getting these errors :

```
    yum -y localinstall http://yum1.stanford.edu/mrepo/ol8-x86 64/RPMS.appstream/oracle-database-preinstall-19c-1.0-2.el8.x86 64.rpm
Loaded plugins: langpacks, ulninfo
Repository ol7_latest is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository ol7_u0_base is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository ol7_u1_base is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository ol7_u2_base is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository ol7_u3_base is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository ol7_u4_base is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository ol7_u5_base is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository ol7_u6_base is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository ol7_security_validation is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository ol7_optional_latest is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository ol7_addons is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository ol7_MODRHCK is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository ol7_latest_archive is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository ol7_optional_archive is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository ol7_UEKR5 is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository ol7_UEKR4 is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository ol7_UEKR3 is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository ol7_UEKR3_OFED20 is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository ol7_UEKR5_RDMA is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository ol7_UEKR4_OFED is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository ol7_UEKR4_archive is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository ol7_UEKR5_archive is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository ol7_kvm_utils is listed more than once in the configuration
Skipping: http://yum1.stanford.edu/mrepo/ol8-x86, filename does not end in .rpm.
Skipping: 64/RPMS.appstream/oracle-database-preinstall-19c-1.0-2.el8.x86, filename does not end in .rpm.
Cannot open: 64.rpm. Skipping.
Nothing to do
```

Comment: Try quotes around the url portion of your yum command:  `yum -y localinstall "http://yum1.stanford.edu/mrepo/ol8-x86 64/RPMS.appstream/oracle-database-preinstall-19c-1.0-2.el8.x86 64.rpm"`

Comment: @SottoVoce still the same error messgaes.

Comment: I think you have somehow changed the underscore character in the url into a space character.  In two places in the url.  Try changing them back to underscore characters.

Answer (score 0):

The URL in `yum` command need to be:

```
  yum -y localinstall http://yum1.stanford.edu/mrepo/ol8-x86_64/RPMS.appstream/oracle-database-preinstall-19c-1.0-2.el8.x86_64.rpm
```

you replace underscore (`_`) with space ( ) in `ol8-x86_64`